# How to declare a function that takes a pointer-to-member function

Tags: c++, qt, function-pointers

I have a class with a member variable pointing to a library object.

```
class myClassA {
private:
    libraryClass *libraryObject;
}
```

The library class emits events, characterised by a string, and provides a mechanism that allows a client class to specify a member function that should be called when the event is emitted, so in *myClassA*, I can do

```
libraryObject->connect ("eventName", this, &myClassA::privateMember);
```

I'd now like clients of *myClassA* to be able to connect their member functions to the event, by adding a public member function *connect* to *myClassA*. How should I declare *connect* in the *myClassA* header file?

Specifically, I'm using Qt and trying to allow clients (of *myClassA*) to call *QScxmlStateMachine::connectToEvent*. The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qscxmlstatemachine.html#connectToEvent-1) for this function describes it as

```
QMetaObject::Connection QScxmlStateMachine::connectToEvent(
            const QString &scxmlEventSpec,
            const QObject *receiver,
            PointerToMemberFunction method,
            Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)
```

but I'm unclear how *PointerToMemberFunction* should be defined.

The Qt header file declares it as

```
template <typename Func1>
QMetaObject::Connection connectToEvent(
        const QString &scxmlEventSpec,
        const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *receiver, Func1 slot,
        Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection);
```

Rather than me just copying this blindly into my code and seeing whether it works, please could someone explain this declaration to me; in particular I read it as saying that something is templated and I don't understand what, and why I don't need to do anything template-y to use the mechanism.

Thanks.

Comment: Use templates, as all [standard C++ algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) taking a predicate does? Or a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? Either of these will make *your* life easier. :)

Comment: If you need to call QScxmlStateMachine::connectToEvent function then you should use same types of arguments. Just use PointerToMemberFunction as a type. connectToEvent expects to receive third argument of this type.

Answer (score 2):

`QtPrivate::FunctionPointer` is a type trait template that helps the new Qt signal/slot syntax.

> ### [How Qt Signals and Slots Work - Part 2 - Qt5 New Syntax](https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work-part2-qt5.html)
>
> #### Type Traits: `QtPrivate::FunctionPointer`
>
> A trait is basically a helper class that gives meta data about a given
>   type. Another example of trait in Qt is `QTypeInfo`.
>
> What we will need to know in order to implement the new syntax is
>   information about a function pointer.
>
> The `template<typename T> struct FunctionPointer` will give us
>   information about `T` via its member.
>
> - `ArgumentCount`: An integer representing the number of arguments of the function.
> - `Object`: Exists only for pointer to member function. It is a typedef to the class of which the function is a member.
> - `Arguments`: Represents the list of argument. It is a typedef to a meta-programming list.
> - `call(T &function, QObject *receiver, void **args)`: A static function that will call the function, applying the given parameters.
>
> ...
>
> The implementation of `FunctionPointer` lies in [qobjectdefs_impl.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs_impl.h.html#QtPrivate::FunctionPointer).

This trait allow to select the right [`QScxmlStateMachine::connectToEvent`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtscxml/src/scxml/qscxmlstatemachine.h.html#266) depending on the provided argument - `QObject` slot, functor or function pointer (both with or without context).

```
// connect state to a QObject slot
template <typename Func1>
inline QMetaObject::Connection connectToEvent(
        const QString &scxmlEventSpec,
        const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *receiver, Func1 slot,
        Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)


// connect state to a functor or function pointer (without context)
template <typename Func1>
inline typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<
        !QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::IsPointerToMemberFunction &&
        !std::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value, QMetaObject::Connection>::Type
connectToEvent(const QString &scxmlEventSpec, Func1 slot,
               Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)

// connectToEvent to a functor or function pointer (with context)
template <typename Func1>
inline typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<
        !QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::IsPointerToMemberFunction &&
        !std::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value, QMetaObject::Connection>::Type
connectToEvent(const QString &scxmlEventSpec, QObject *context, Func1 slot, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)
```

So if you need to allow all cases you could provide methods with the same prototypes and forward the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Following through all the various include files while formulating the question has allowed me to resolve this issue.

I have included the following in the header file for *myClassA*

```
template <typename Func1>           // Lifted from QtScxmlStateMachine.h
QMetaObject::Connection connectToEvent(
        const QString &scxmlEventSpec,
        const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *receiver, Func1 slot,
        Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection) {
    return libraryObject->connectToEvent(scxmlEventSpec, receiver, slot, type);
};
```

Clients of *myClassA* can now call *myClassA::connectToEvent* to call the underlying *QtScxmlStateMachine*'s *connectToEvent* member.

Thank you, StackOverflow, for forcing me to get my thoughts properly in order.