# How to emit a Qt signal from inside a function pointer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17, signals-slots

While implementing the interface to a device there is code like the following in `MyClass` constructor

```
pDeviceInstance = new Device()
pDeviceInstance->loadLibrary();
pDeviceInstance->Create(functionpointer)
```

There are asyncronous events comming out and calling `functionpointer` (which I would like to deal with).

Both `functionpointer` and `pDeviceInstance` are `static`.
I would like to emit a Qt signal from inside `functionpointer` but because it is `static` its not possible to emit the signal.

I tried:

1. To make `functionpointer` a lambda in the hope to emit signals from inside the lambda.
   But for that to happen lambda needs to capture `this`,
   and in order for the lambda to decay to a function pointer it cannot capture anything.
2. To make `functionpointer` non `static` but in that case it seems to be a function pointer of `MyClass`
   which is different type.

So, I'm running out of options in my plan of emit a Qt signal from inside that `functionpointer`.
Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443524/7582247) seems to explain what you can do.

Comment: May I ask you to be a litte more verbose, I read it but I didn't got the idea.

Comment: I don't know Qt so it's probably best if you post a new question about how to set it up using the `QtPrivate::FunctionPointer` if [the blog post](https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work-part2-qt5.html) doesn't explain it in enough detail.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer) relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem at all. Hook up a `QObject` with the signals you desire as a child of `qApp` (`QApplication::instance`), and then use it via the global `qApp` pointer:

```
class MySignaler : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MySignaler(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {
    setParent(qApp);
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void deviceActivity();
  static bool emitDeviceActivity() {
    if (!qApp) return false;
    auto *self = qApp->findChild<MySignaler*>();
    if (!self) return false;
    emit self->deviceActivity();
    return true;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MySignaler signaler;
  Device device;
  device.loadLibrary();
  device.create(&MySignaler::emitDeviceActivity);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Well, in this case it seems I have to change signature of ‘functionpointer’?